# How to replace images with new ones, instead of adding to page after API submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api

Im building a random DogAPI image generator, where you put a number from 1-50 into a form text box, hit send, and it displays random dog photos of that amount.

The page is working, but when you choose a new or same number, it adds that new amount of photos to the page, instead of replacing them. Help!

```js
'use strict';

function getDogImage(text) {
  fetch(`https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random/${text}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => displayResults(responseJson));
}

function watchForm() {
  $('form').submit(event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    var text = $('.number').val();
    if (text < 50) {
      getDogImage(text);
    } else {
      alert('Number must be between 1-50')
    };
  });
}

function displayResults(responseJson) {
  console.log(responseJson);
  for (let i = 0; i < responseJson.message.length; i++) {
    $('.results').append(
      `<img src="${responseJson.message[i]}" class="results-img">`
    )
  };

  $('.results').removeClass('hidden');
}

$(function() {
  console.log('App loaded! Waiting for submit!');
  watchForm();
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>How Many?</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>How Many Dog Pics Do You Want?</h1>
    <p>Pick a number between 1-50</p>
    <form>
      <input class="number" value="3" type="text" placeholder="1-50?" required>
      <input type="submit" value="Show me the doggies!">
    </form>
    <section class="results hidden">
      <h2>Here you go!</h2>
    </section>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would clear the contents of the results div, and then add the new images. To do this, though, I needed to make a few changes:

First, move the `<h1>` out of the `.results` div. Then, before your loop where you append the images, use [`.empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) to clear the contents of the results div. Then your loop will run and fill it with the new images.

```js
'use strict';

function getDogImage(text) {
  fetch(`https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random/${text}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => displayResults(responseJson));
}

function watchForm() {
  $('form').submit(event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    var text = $('.number').val();
    if (text < 50) {
      getDogImage(text);
    } else {
      alert('Number must be between 1-50')
    };
  });
}

function displayResults(responseJson) {
  console.log(responseJson);
  $('.results').empty();
  for (let i = 0; i < responseJson.message.length; i++) {
    $('.results').append(
      `<img src="${responseJson.message[i]}" class="results-img">`
    )
  };

  $('.results').removeClass('hidden');
}

$(function() {
  console.log('App loaded! Waiting for submit!');
  watchForm();
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>How Many?</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>How Many Dog Pics Do You Want?</h1>
    <p>Pick a number between 1-50</p>
    <form>
      <input class="number" value="3" type="text" placeholder="1-50?" required>
      <input type="submit" value="Show me the doggies!">
    </form>
    <h2>Here you go!</h2>
    <section class="results hidden">
    </section>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```